# Android app crashes if I declare more than 3 Drawables

Tags: android

I'm making a simple dice app in Android Studio right now and I have 6 Drawables for each side of a die. Here is what the code looks like:

```
final Drawable die1 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.die1);
final Drawable die2 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.die2);
final Drawable die3 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.die3);
final Drawable die4 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.die4);
final Drawable die5 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.die5);
final Drawable die6 = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.die6);
```

The app runs fine when three of the drawables are commented out, but doesn't run in the emulator if more than 3 are uncommented. I tried fixing this by building an apk and running the app on my phone, but it doesn't run even if one of the drawables are uncommented. If they are, the app runs, but it's a blank screen.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't run? Is it crashing? If so please post logcat error output.

Comment: If you use Android Studio, use memory monitor to check how much memory it's using, it might be a memory problem.

Comment: Yes it's crashing. It's saying "Unfortunately, TheApp has stopped" on the emulator and     

Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 98406412 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"

on logcat

Comment: Paste the stacktrace from logcat in android studio

Comment: The stack trace:
    
    Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 98406412 byte       allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 7MB until OOM"
    --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
    Shutting down VM
     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process:     com.example.pahul.simpledice, PID: 25869
                                                                              java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 98406412 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 7MB until OOM

Answer (score 1):

As it is `OutOfMemory` error, you can use small size png images to overcome `OutOfMemory` error. If you want to use existing images, you can shrink your images using [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/) online tool.

Answer (score 0):

First why you need to use use many image file in drawable, If you really need to load as many image then resize them one by one. If you want to load then on imageview then you can use Picasso library. Some of the solutions can be

1. scale the image to low size  https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html
2. use picasso library or other if loading image in image view
3. Clear Memory every time while loading image. This will help to manage out of memory error. use LRU chache class
   http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-picasso--cms-22149
4. Use Device with more Memory